# Access Kubernetes GKE cluster outside of GKE cluster with client-go?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

- I have multiple kubernetes clusters running on GKE (let's say clusterA and clusterB)
- I want to access both of those clusters from client-go in an app that is running in one of those clusters (e.g. access clusterB from an app that is running on clusterA)

I general for authenticating with kubernetes clusters from client-go I see that I have two options:

- InCluster config
- or from kube config file

So it is easy to access clusterA from clusterA but not clusterB from clusterA.

What are my options here? It seems that I just cannot pass `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` and hope that client-go will take care of itself.

So my thinking:

- create a dedicated IAM service account
- create kube config with tokens for both clusters by doing `gcloud container clusters get-credentials clusterA` and `gcloud container clusters get-credentials clusterB`
- use that kube config file in client-go via `BuildConfigFromFlags` on clusterA

Is this the correct approach, or is there a simpler way? I see that tokens have an expiration date?

**Update:**

It seems I can also use `CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_USE_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE=True gcloud beta container clusters get-credentials clusterB --zone`. Which would add certificates to kube conf which I could use. But AFAIK those certificates cannot be revoked

Answer (score 12, accepted):

client-go needs to know about:

1. cluster master’s IP address
2. cluster’s CA certificate

(If you're using GKE, you can see these info in `$HOME/.kube/config`, populated by `gcloud container clusters get-credentials` command).

I recommend you to either:

1. Have a kubeconfig file that contains these info for clusters A & B
2. Use GKE API to retrieve these info for clusters A & B ([example here](https://ahmet.im/blog/gke-api/)) (You'll need a service account to do this, explained below.)

Once you can create a `*rest.Config` object in client-go, client-go will use the auth plugin that's specified in the kubeconfig file (or its in-memory equivalent you constructed).  In `gcp` auth plugin, it knows how to retrieve a token.

Then, [Create a Cloud IAM Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts) and give it "Container Developer" role. Download its key.

Now, you have two options:

#### Option 1: your program uses gcloud

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=key.json
KUBECONFIG=a.yaml gcloud container clusters get-credentials clusterA
KUBECONFIG=b.yaml gcloud container clusters get-credentials clusterB
```

Then create 2 different `*rest.Client` objects, one created from `a.yaml`, another from `b.yaml` in your program.

Now your program will rely on `gcloud` binary to retrieve token every time your token expires (every 1 hour).

#### Option 2: use GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

1. Don't install gcloud to your program’s environment.
2. Set your key.json to GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment 
   variable for your program.
3. Figure out a way to get cluster IP/CA (explained above) so you can
   construct two different `*rest.Config` objects for cluster A & B.
4. Now your program will use the specified key file to get an access_token
   to Google API every time it expires (every 1h).

Hope this helps.

P.S. do not forget to `import _ "k8s.io/client-go/plugin/pkg/client/auth/gcp"` in your Go program. This loads the gcp auth plugin!

Comment: Are you sure that option 2 would work? Cause looking at gcp.go implementation it seems that it does require external binary to refresh tokens?

Comment: Ok, it seems that I got confused with 2nd option by looking at gcp.go which describes cmd-path and cmd-args, so I thought that it's the same as using gcloud, but it seems that if you don't provide those, it will just use google.DefaultTokenSource which seems to be what I need

Comment: Great to hear. I recently updated that file, both options are possible.

Comment: @AhmetAlpBalkan-Google Is the first method safe to use in production?

Comment: @AhmetB-Google do you know how to pass IP/CA to client-go?

Comment: No idea. Please open a new question to ask.