# Google container cluster as config

Tags: go, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-go-client

I am trying to use the [kubernetes go-client](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go) with cloud.google.com/go/container. I create the cluster using the google cloud go container package, then I want to deploy on that cluster using go-client. The [out of cluster example](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/examples/out-of-cluster-client-configuration/main.go) given by the go-client uses the kube config file to get the credentials for the cluster. But since I just created this cluster within my application I don’t have that config file.

How can I setup a “k8s.io/client-go/rest” config with a "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/container/v1" Cluster? What are the required fields? The code below is what I currently have (without showing the actual CA certificate).

```
func getConfig(cluster *containerproto.Cluster) *rest.Config {
    return &rest.Config{
        Host:     "https://" + cluster.GetEndpoint(),
        TLSClientConfig: rest.TLSClientConfig{
            Insecure: false,
            CAData: []byte(`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
                ...
                -----END CERTIFICATE-----`),
        },
    }
```

It results in this error: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority. So there is obviously something missing.
Any other approach is more than welcome! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ClientCertificate, ClientKey and ClusterCaCertificate need to be decoded as described [here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-kubernetes/issues/85)

```
func CreateK8sClientFromCluster(cluster *gkev1.Cluster) {
    decodedClientCertificate, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(cluster.MasterAuth.ClientCertificate)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("decode client certificate error:", err)
        return
    }
    decodedClientKey, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(cluster.MasterAuth.ClientKey)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("decode client key error:", err)
        return
    }
    decodedClusterCaCertificate, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(cluster.MasterAuth.ClusterCaCertificate)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("decode cluster CA certificate error:", err)
        return
    }

    config := &rest.Config{
        Username: cluster.MasterAuth.Username,
        Password: cluster.MasterAuth.Password,
        Host:     "https://" + cluster.Endpoint,
        TLSClientConfig: rest.TLSClientConfig{
            Insecure: false,
            CertData: decodedClientCertificate,
            KeyData:  decodedClientKey,
            CAData:   decodedClusterCaCertificate,
        },
    }

    clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("failed to get k8s client set from config: %s\n", err)
        return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've answered a very similar question here: [Access Kubernetes GKE cluster outside of GKE cluster with client-go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48400966/access-kubernetes-gke-cluster-outside-of-gke-cluster-with-client-go/48412272#48412272).

Basically, in a nutshell, the recommended way to do this is to:

1. Create a Google Cloud IAM service account + download its json key
2. Set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var to that key.json
3. Find IP address and CA cert of the cluster from `gcloud container clusters describe` (or simply get a `.kube/config` file from `gcloud get-credentials`
4. Pass these values to client-go and run your program with the env var.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! However it is not working yet. I set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to my service account json file that has "Kubernetes Engine Admin" and "Kubernetes Engine Cluster Admin" as role. For now I am using gcloud `container clusters describe` and hardcode the fields for `rest.Config` Username, password, host and use `clusterCaCertificate` field to set the `CAData` in `rest.TLSClientConfig`.

Within my application I am using "cloud.google.com/go/container" and I ideally don't want to execute gcloud commands. How can I get the data from the container package?

Comment: There's examples of using GKE API in Python and Go here: https://ahmet.im/blog/gke-api/. GKE has client libraries published in all languages supported by GCP client libraries. You can use them. Just take a look at `gcloud` command with `--log-http` to see the request.

Comment: That worked to get the data within my application. Thank you. However I am still not able to connect to the cluster using the go-client with that CA data, username, password and endpoint. Is there maybe something like a firewall blocking it?

Comment: I also found your issue in [the go-client issues](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/issues/416). I see that you are using the BearerToken. Do I also have to use this for gke? Where would I get that?

Comment: Nope, don't use bearer token. Use the service account key by setting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env variable and `import _ "k8s.io/client-go/plugin/pkg/client/auth/gcp"` package. See `client-go` examples/ directory.